# name generator for different match each time

Tags: javascript, html

```js
   var nameone = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"];

var nametwo = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p"];

function getNewName() {
  var nameone, nametwo}

for(var i =0;i<nameone.length;i++)

getNewName = Math.floor(Math.random()* nameone.length);
```

```html
   <form>

<input type="number" name="number" >
<button onclick="getNewName">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. See if you can fix the obvious mistakes (Press F12 for console)

Comment: Hint: >The first `}` needs to go after the end of the code and you call a function with brackets: `getNewName()` - that name has to match the function you have - in this case not getNewName

Comment: Other hint - a submit button does not have min/max attributes and you do not want to submit your form. You want to stay on the page

Comment: If you do not use an array, you need to split your strings first and last on comma

Comment: Thankyou so much, i have tried to change the things you mentioned but i cannot see the snippet, how does it looks now?

Comment: What browser? Use chrome

Comment: You cannot have the same name for a function and a variable

Comment: Also your loop sets the same var over and over

Comment: what if i use length in the loop?

Comment: See my answer for a full solution - I really should make you work harder if this is homework

Comment: That is EXACTLY what i mean thankyou so much, haha no it isn't luckily im just finding task online for my self to solve cause im teaching myself right now...slow but steady:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
var first = ["Graesin", "Jerry", "Tray", "Montrel", "Luke", "Max", "Alex", "Nina", "Austin", "Mike"];

var last = ["Brownell", "Songs", "Andersen", "Tyler", "Beha", "Delgado", "Kaur", "Adams", "Jones", "Harris"];

function getNewName() {
  var arr = [];
  var num = document.getElementById("num").value; // get the number of names
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    arr.push(
      first[Math.floor(Math.random() * first.length)] + " " +
      last[Math.floor(Math.random() * last.length)]);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = arr.join('<br/>'); // div
    document.getElementById("outputfield").value = arr.join('\n'); // textarea
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="num" min=1 max=20 />
  <button type="button" onclick="getNewName()">Submit</button>
  <div id="output"></div>

  <textarea id="outputfield"></textarea>

</form>
```